# How do I get jQuery .expander to invoke on load and not just on click?

Tags: jquery, live, expand, expander

I am having problems with jQuery .expander function and invoking it when the page loads and I know it has to do with the data being dynamically populated with jQuery.

**NOTE: It looks like altering the actual Ajax functions is not going to be an option.**

It was suggested to try .live() which has worked well but there are issues with div.tags-hidden being bound over and over again.

Then it was suggested that I use a variable "bound" and check to see if div.tags-hidden has been bound first and if not set the variable to true which in effect disables .expander for any other div.tags-hidden.

*So, there are actually two issues which I would be grateful for any advice on:*

1) The .expander function is not invoking until a click occurs

2) The div.tags-hidden that the user clicks first is the only one to have the .expander feature.

The slides below hopefully illustrate this better (see below for images).

**SLIDE 1:** On load the .expander function is not kicking in

**SLIDE 2:** The .expander only happens when a click happens

**SLIDE 3:** The current function to invoke .expander (see below for code). This includes the
variable bound=false. This was a recommended when using .live() but this is causing problems

**SLIDE 4:** Back to the UI, these two modules contain plenty of tags to invoke the .expander
function but only the first div.tags-hidden clicked is getting this treatment. This is due to the "bound" variable being set to false which forces the expander treatment to just one div.tags-hidden, the first one clicked.

To sum it up:
How can I get all the div.tags-hidden to contain the .expander function onload?

Here is the current jQuery I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bound = false;
$('div.tags-hidden').live('load click', function() {
    if(!bound) {
      $(this).find('p').expander({
      slicePoint:       50,
      expandText:         '<img src="/images/layout/site/btn_expand.png" alt="Click to Expand Tags" title="Click to Expand Tags">', 
      collapseTimer:    0, 
      userCollapseText: '<img src="/images/layout/site/btn_collapse.png" alt="Click to Collapse Tags" title="Click to Collapse Tags">'
  });
        bound = true;
    }
});
</script>
```

**Here are the Slides:**

[image: Slide 1]

[image: Slide 2]

[image: Slide 3]

[image: Slide 4]

Very thankful for any help with this. 
Mitch

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that everything is ready for you before trying to act upon it. AKA $(document).ready();

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var bound = false;
$('div.tags-hidden').live('load click', function() {
    if(!bound) {
      $(this).find('p').expander({
      slicePoint:       50,
      expandText:         '<img src="/images/layout/site/btn_expand.png" alt="Click to Expand Tags" title="Click to Expand Tags">', 
      collapseTimer:    0, 
      userCollapseText: '<img src="/images/layout/site/btn_collapse.png" alt="Click to Collapse Tags" title="Click to Collapse Tags">'
  });
        bound = true;
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try this but it didn't work. I think it's due to the fact that the data isn't there yet and I have to invoke .expander function when the Ajax call is made. The problem is it may not be available so I am trying to find a work around.